# Mvc Form data is not post to the Asp.net Web API Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have following cshtml in my view:

```
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("Designation")
            .DataValueField("Designation")
            .DataTextField("Designation")
            .SelectedIndex(0)
            .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Designation"]))
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("DeptId")
            .DataValueField("DeptId")
            .DataTextField("DeptName")
            .SelectedIndex(0)
            .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Department"]))
    <input class="k-button" id="btnFilter" type="submit" value="Filter" />
</div>
```

I want to post the value of both dropdownlist to my Web ApiController. I have created the following jquery ajax method to call the api. But it is not working.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnFilter").click(function () {
            debugger;
            var designation = $("#Designation").val();
            var deptname = $("#DeptId").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8648/api/Employee" + deptname + designation,
                type: "Post",
                // data: JSON.stringify([designation, deptname]), //{ Name: name, 
                // Address: address, DOB: dob },
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) { alert("posted") },
                error: function () { alert('error'); }
            });
        });
    });
```

Here is my API Controller Post Method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostEmployee(EmployeeViewModel newEmployee, String deptname, String designation)
        {
           //code
        }
```

How can i send the value of dropdownlost to my ApiController.

Comment: `API Controller` cannot accept parameters like that. Add `deptname` and `designation` as properties of your `EmployeeViewModel` or create new model altogether.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `GET` method whereas your API method is `POST`

your request will look like something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnFilter").click(function () {
            debugger;
            var designation = $("#Designation").val();
            var deptname = $("#DeptId").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8648/api/Employee/PostEmployee",
                type: "Post",
                data: {"newEmployee":/*your serialized data for the model*/,
                      "deptname":deptname ,"designation":designation }
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) { alert("posted") },
                error: function () { alert('error'); }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: you are not specifying method name in your request

Answer (score 0):

According to your question you want to post only dropdown data then 
Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnFilter").click(function () {
            debugger;
            var designation = $("#Designation").val();
            var deptname = $("#DeptId").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8648/api/Employee?deptname="+deptname+"&designation="+designation ,
                type: "Post",                    
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) { alert("posted") },
                error: function () { alert('error'); }
            });
        });
    });
```

Api controller

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostEmployee(String deptname, String designation)
        {
           //code
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send the data as part of the request url. You would only do this if you were making a get request.

If you wish to do this as a get request you need to specify in your `$.ajax` function that it's a GET request and construct the url correctly:

```
$.ajax({
          //construct the url with the data as part of the query string
          url: "http://localhost:8648/api/Employee?deptname="+deptname+"&designation="+designation ,
          //specify it's a get request
          type: "GET",                    
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          success: function (data) { alert("posted") },
          error: function () { alert('error'); }
      });
});
```

With your api controller like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage PostEmployee(String deptname, String designation)
{

}
```

However, if you wish to do this as a POST request you need to send the data in the body of the request:

```
$.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:8648/api/Employee,
          //specify it's a POSTrequest
          type: "POST",                    
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          //send data as part of body
          data: {designation: designation, deptname: deptname}
          success: function (data) { alert("posted") },
          error: function () { alert('error'); }
      });
});
```

With your api controller looking like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PostEmployee(String deptname, String designation)
{

}
```

Comment: That's not necessarily the case.  There is no reason a POST cannot contain some data in the URI and some in the POST body.